# Collection DataProvider - Strange behavior

Tags: magento2, collection, data-provider

I've been killing for hours and no result. I don't understand this strange behavior, can anyone please explain this to me? It's unbelievable ... Thanks for All!!!

```
$this->collection = $Collection;

$datum = $this->getRequest->getParam('datum');
    
$reportId = $this->DataHelper->getReportId($datum); // return 1 - No results
//$reportId = 1; // when I uncomment this, result will OK

$this->collection->getSelect()->where("report_id = '".(int) $reportId."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$reportId = (int) $this->DataHelper->getReportId($datum);

$this->collection->getSelect()->where("report_id = ?", $reportId);
```

Comment: //print_r($reportId); die(); // return 1
$this->collection->getSelect()->where("report_id = ?", $reportId); // no result
$this->collection->getSelect()->where("report_id = ?", 1); // result ok

Omg, It is incomprehensible that it does not work..

Comment: @DavidSynek "print_r($reportId); die();" will always return 1. you shoud try echo instead print_r. I think your $reportId is 0 all the time.

Comment: echo($reportId); die(); will return 1

Comment: Can you print the query? echo $this->collection->getSelect()->__toString();

Comment: Yes, when I check query is return true.
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `dawe_zasilky` AS `main_table` WHERE (report_id = 1)

I think something is broken, this just has to work.

Comment: Then the problem is not for the variable. Log the query instead of die, then you can get correct data. I thing this class will call multiple time, and some times reportId is 0.